# Adding Value To Quantity and Stock Status

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.3

**I would like to add a value to the stock status that says "coming soon" for products that are currently in production. However, I do not see where I can add an option in the attribute values.**

> How would I do this?

[image: Dropdown]

Answer (score 1):

**The easiest way is to create a new attribute checkbox.**

> Create a product attribute called `is_coming_soon`,visible on front
>   and create this function in a view_model.

Declare your view model in app/design/frontend/YourVendor/default/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml by adding this :

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.stock">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="product_list_view_model" xsi:type="object">YourVendor\Catalog\ViewModel\isComingSoon</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Create your ViewModel in app/code/YourVendor/Catalog/ViewModel/isComingSoon.php

```
class isComingSoon extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct
    {
        public function isComingSoon()
        {
            $product = $this->getProduct();
            $stockMessage = 'Out of stock';

            if ($product->getIsComingSoon()) {
                $stockMessage = 'Coming soon';
            }

           return $stockMessage;
        }
    }
```

In your templates `list.phtml` override the status like this :

```
    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
       <div class="product-details__stock product-details__stock--available"><span><?= __('In Stock') ?></span></div>
    <?php else: ?>
       <div class="product-details__stock product-details__stock--unavailable"><span><?= __($viewModel->isComingSoon()) ?></span></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Do the same for templates : `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml` and `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml`

**With this code 'Coming soon' will be displayed if the checkbox is true and product out of stock.**

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know which file I should add the view_model to? And would I have to add the status override in grid.phtml and listing.phtml as well?

Comment: I added lines in my answer

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I tried it and it just makes half the inventory not render but the out of stock still comes up

Comment: And even after restoring original files, flushing the cache, and reindexing they're not coming back up

Comment: Did you setup:di:compile ?

Comment: An outside developer is the command line user, I only have backend and ftp access, is there another way?